# How do I get the tally of items in a list based on a another list using python?

Tags: python, list, count

I want to tally the items in a list. I use the following:

```
from collections import Counter
list1 = ['a', 'b','a', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b']
tally_items = Counter(list1)
```

But in the list it's possible not all the unique items I want appear.
For example, list1 has 'a', 'b', 'c' but I want 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'.

I could use something like this:

```
list0 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
tally_items = [list1.count(i) for i in list0]
```

Are there any other ways ?

Comment: Note that if you ask a counter for the count of something it hasn't counted, you get 0. For example, in your first snippet, `tally_items['e'] == 0`.

Answer (score 3):

An instance of `Counter` will already return `0` for any key that does not explicitly exist. So in the above example:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b','a', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b']
tally_items = Counter(list1)
print tally_items['d'] # prints 0
```

If you want to explicitly have these keys, you create a counter with all of the keys initialized to `0`:

```
tally_list = Counter()
for key in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']:
    tally_list[key] = 0
```

Then you can update it with the list of actual items:

```
tally_list.update(list1)
print tally_list # prints Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'e': 0, 'd': 0})
```